# Leaflet how to select a default map when fully loaded

Tags: leaflet

So I've been collecting Map Layers from the leaflet map providers and the webpage doesn't load any layer map, I have to manually select it. 
[This is the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBAzE.png)

This is the code:

```
// center of the map
var center = [14.240861626831018, 121.12966240455648];

// Create the map
var map = L.map('map', {attributionControl: false}).setView(center, 13);

//Layer Map
var osm = L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
{   
    maxZoom: 15,
    minZoom:13
}),
googleTerrain = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=p&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',
{
    maxZoom: 15,
    minZoom:13,
    subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']
}),
mlight = L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw',
{
    maxZoom: 15,
    minZoom:13,
    id: 'mapbox.light'
}),
darkmatter = L.tileLayer('https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', 
{
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>',
    subdomains: 'abcd',
    maxZoom: 19
}),
googleSat = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s,h&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',
{   
    maxZoom: 15,
    minZoom:13,
    subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']
});

var baseMaps = {
    "Street": osm,
    "Terrain":googleTerrain,
    "Satellite": googleSat,
    "Dark": darkmatter,
    "MonoLight":mlight,
};

var overlays =  {
    };
L.control.layers(baseMaps,overlays, {position: 'bottomright'}).addTo(map);
```

I tried searching through the leaflet website, am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not adding any of those `L.TileLayer`s to the map (e.g. `foo = L.tileLayer(...).addTo(map)`). Simply add the one you want to be enabled by default.

Keep in mind that a `L.Control.Layers` does **not** perform any initial checks about whether any of the layers specified as basemaps are already on the map or not. It has been [suggested as a feature](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4925) but no work about it has been undertaken (as of yet).